# Saving player progress so it will be tamper proof

Tags: iphone

How can I save a file in iPhone sdk and make it hack-proof(for example the levels the player has passed)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to encrypt the contents of the file.

It won't be 100% hack proof, but it may make it much harder to edit due to the effort of locating the encryption keys on your code, etc. So many users won't be able to.

Otherwise, store the progress in an external server (that will require internet connection) so you are in control of that data. But it may not suit your game.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-rooted iPhone, just saving the file locally should make it hack-[resistant](http://xkcd.com/538/). If for some reason you're worried hackers using rooted phones, then encrypting the local file, or relying on remote storage (over encrypted communication) would make it [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) more hack-resistant.